# My added eventhandler working once only when the page is loaded

Tags: javascript, eventhandler

I am trying to check if user change field while it is still empty.And I'm adding event listener on the username field so when the user move from one field to other then he get either a check sign or an error.
**My HTML File:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Registeration form</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontawesome.css"/> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" style="display:inline;float:left;" placeholder="User Name">
                <li id="name_status" style="list-style-type:none;"></li>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email"  style="display:inline;float:left;" placeholder="Email Address">
                <li id="email_status" style="list-style-type:none;"></li>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/test.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**My Javascript file:**

```
var user_name=document.getElementById("user_name");
var user_name_status=document.getElementById("name_status");

user_name.addEventListener("blur",check_empty(user_name.value,user_name_status),false);
function check_empty(value,status){
    if(value.length===0){
        status.innerHTML="<sup>*</sup>This feild cannot be empty";
    } else {
        status.innerHTML="<i class='icon-check'></i>";
    }
}
```

Comment: You are calling the function immediately.

Comment: so what is the right way

Comment: I'm a newbie so can you suggest some code

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `check_empty` immediately. You can pass function reference `check_empty` to `.addEventListener()`. Within event handler, `this` references `user_name`. Instead of passing variable `status`, utilize the defined varibale `user_name_status` within event handler.

```js
var user_name = document.getElementById("user_name");
var user_name_status = document.getElementById("name_status");

user_name.addEventListener("blur", check_empty, false);

function check_empty(e) {
  if (this.value.length === 0) {
    user_name_status.innerHTML = "<sup>*</sup>This feild cannot be empty";
  } else {
    user_name_status.innerHTML = "<i class='icon-check'>check</i>";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Registeration form</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="post">
    <fieldset>
      <input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" style="display:inline;float:left;" placeholder="User Name">
      <li id="name_status" style="list-style-type:none;"></li>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" style="display:inline;float:left;" placeholder="Email Address">
      <li id="email_status" style="list-style-type:none;"></li>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How can I add an event on the specific field only like I was using blur is it right? @guest271314

Comment: I was passing two arguments because later on I'll be passing multiple fields like email and others through the same function @guest271314

Comment: Yes, the variables are defined outside of function. You can use reference to defined variables which represent element. You can use `.bind()` to pass variables to function.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option for you is to pass the function with argument inside an anonymous function like the code below shows.

```js
var user_name = document.getElementById("user_name");
var user_name_status = document.getElementById("name_status");  

user_name.addEventListener("blur",function(){check_empty(user_name.value,user_name_status);},false);
function check_empty(name,status) {
  if (name.length === 0) {
    status.innerHTML = "<sup>*</sup>This feild cannot be empty";
  } else {
    status.innerHTML = "<i class='icon-check'>check</i>";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Registeration form</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="post">
    <fieldset>
      <input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" style="display:inline;float:left;" placeholder="User Name">
      <li id="name_status" style="list-style-type:none;"></li>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" style="display:inline;float:left;" placeholder="Email Address">
      <li id="email_status" style="list-style-type:none;"></li>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```